# Qt5 on windows can't find QSqlDatabase

Tags: windows, qt, sqlite

I try to use sqlite on some qt app but getting error on compile step

```
Cannot open include file: 'QSqlDatabase': No such file or directory
```

I use Windows7, qt5.1 compiled with MSVC 2010. I have qsqlite.dll(and other .dlls) in ..Qt_path/plugins/sqldrivers

in my file I try include QSqlDatabase

```
#include <QSqlDatabase>
```

and in my .pro file

```
QT += core \
      ...
      sql
```

Use Qt Creator to compile the app. What do I do wrong?

UPD: I made simple program to check which drivers are available.

```
#include <QtCore/QCoreApplication>
#include <QSqlDatabase>
#include <QtSQL>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    qDebug() << QSqlDatabase::drivers();
    return a.exec();
}
```

and it works without any problems. Have no idea why it doesn't with the main app

FIXED: for some reason some files were not updated in the 'build' and 'release' folders and that is why app didn't want to find sql. removed 'build' and 'release' folders completely, build again and it works.

Comment: Did you _run qmake_ after you added _sql_ to your .pro file and before you try to build your project?

Comment: I use Qt Creator and it does it automatically. And yes. I tried it manually also

Comment: could you supply the contents from the Compilation - View?

Comment: do you mean the output drivers? ("QSQLITE", "QODBC", "QODBC3", "QPSQL", "QPSQL7"). But it is not important. The problem that the second app runs without error with the same include and sql in .pro files

Comment: Make sure you didn't miss the character '\' at the end of the line before _sql_ in the _.pro_ file (QT += ).

LE: _run qmake_ after you modify the .pro file just to be sure